# Python pptx: "Show legend without overlapping the chart"

Tags: python-pptx

I would like to set legend position to "Show legend without overlapping the chart". How do I do this?

I see that I can set the legend position through:

```
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LEGEND_POSITION

chart.has_legend = True

chart.legend.position = XL_LEGEND_POSITION.BOTTOM
```

There's a CUSTOM option for XL_LEGEND_POSITION according to the [documentation](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpython-pptx.readthedocs.io%2Fen%2Flatest%2Fapi%2Fenum%2FXlLegendPosition.html%23xllegendposition&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHUrmLgMoTkdOzkujU9nV28fJqZEg). Is there a way I can use the CUSTOM option to specify that I would like to show legend without overlapping chart? Below is a screenshot of the Powerpoint option to do this:
["Show legend without overlapping the chart" select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avjao.png)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is `.include_in_layout` on the `Legend` object:

http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#legend-objects

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.